# Search google images and return image address

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have seen a few examples/posts even on SO, but none really help and all involve downloading an image or using GoogleCustom Search API. Is there a way that I can search https://images.google.com for a query (eg: cute dogs) and return an image address of one of the results' image link which I can then open?

Edit: the search site is not limited to images.google is there a way I could for it for a site like Imgur as well?